# Terminology - optical (visual) properties of a structure

Tags: optics, terminology, geometry, vision

I am trying to understand few terminological problems that I encounter. Without knowing keywords it is hard to perform search for literature or publications in the area.
The area relates to the problem of observing planar geometrical periodical structures and determining their quality, such as being more "*optically released*" so to say, like in mechanics. In other words the structure which visually has most possible "*smooth image*".
Let restrict the case only for periodical structures which are of very ordered nature, so those could be called "geometrical crystals". And also count only connected monochrome structures, like for example a simple outlined hexagonal tiling.

It is a lot of things in one, I believe, so the question for now is:

- What term in literature is close to this quality/property of the structure image? And what name has the research area where it belongs?

Other phenomena which is observable and could be described in english as "*the speed of conversion of the structure image to a gray shade by the process of shrinking (downsampling) of the image*". How the latter phenomena could be called?

Consider for example observing following two structures (my own artwork, just in case):

[image]